# Importing multiple access databases into one sql server database

Tags: sql-server

I have four Access database MDB files (all fortunately with different table names in each) and I need to import the four MDB files into one SQL Server 2008 database.

I have tried using SSMS to do an import but the import is removing identity and primary keys and so forth.

I have tried trying to find the correct answer but I don't seem to be able to get all the information I need hence asking here.

Is it possible to achieve completely retaining keys and identities etc using SQL Server import, or is there a tool available I don't know about that will be able to do this?

SR

Comment: If you are importing into a new database, why not use SQL Server 2016, the most recent version?

Comment: I am using 2016 SSMS but the database itself is for 2014 - should that cause any issues?

Also, is 2016 into 2014 better at retaining identities and primary keys etc?

Comment: Then why does your question say SQL Server 2008 ???

Answer (score 0):

Create the tables first in SSMS and set up the primary keys etc, then import the Access data into these newly created tables. Alternatively, is the Access 'Upsizing Wizard' an option?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the info.  I don't think upsize is an option but the former suggestion I think is the only way forwards.